# How to capture one of the two words using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have these 4 regexes

```
1) \w+\s\\bmillion\\b 
2) \w+\s\\bmillions\\b 
3) \w+\s\\bbillion\\b 
4) \w+\s\\bbillions\\b
```

How can i combine them together I tried () and [] but because of \b seems it does not work properly? TIA!

Comment: Please describe what you actually want to achieve; what is the goal of the final regex?

Comment: To capture an instances of words million(s) and biillion(s) with the word before it. I just want to combine output of all 4 regexes above in one

Comment: You should put that in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them using a character class for `[mb]` and an optional `s` at the end.

As the `\s` is mandatory in the pattern, you can omit the first word boundary.

```
\w+\s[mb]illions?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dxaXs/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\w+\s[mb]illions?\b"
strings = ["a million", "a millions", "a billion", "a billions", "a millionx", "a millionsx", "a billionx", "a billionsx"]


for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output

```
a million
a millions
a billion
a billions
```